# Can't change Width of Custom ErrorBars

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I am trying to create ErrorBars in a chart via Excel VBA, but I need the width to be 12PT, or to vary. Here is the code I'm using, but it doesn't look like it's working:

```
Set s = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries() 
With s 
    .Name = "=GraphicSchedule!$" & getColumn(objList.ListColumns.Item("Activity").Range.Column) & "$" & sourceRow 
    .XValues = "=GraphicSchedule!$" & getColumn(objList.ListColumns.Item("DateMid").Range.Column) & "$" & sourceRow 
    .Values = "=GraphicSchedule!$" & getColumn(objList.ListColumns.Item("Loc1").Range.Column) & "$" & sourceRow 
    .HasErrorBars = True 
    .ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlErrorBarIncludeBoth, Type:=xlErrorBarTypeCustom, Amount:="=GraphicSchedule!$" & getColumn(objList.ListColumns.Item("BarLength").Range.Column) & "$" & sourceRow, MinusValues:="=GraphicSchedule!$" & getColumn(objList.ListColumns.Item("BarLength").Range.Column) & "$" & sourceRow 
    Set eB = .ErrorBars 
    With eB 
        With .Format.Line 
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .Style = msoLineSingle
            .Weight = 12
        End With
        .EndStyle = xlNoCap
    End With
    .HasDataLabels = True
    Set dLabels = .DataLabels
    With dLabels
        .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, "=GraphicSchedule!$" & getColumn(objList.ListColumns.Item("Activity").Range.Column) & "$" & sourceRow
        .ShowRange = True
        .ShowSeriesName = False
        .ShowValue = False
    End With
End With
```

I figured using the Weight property would work, but did I overlook something?

Comment: Works fine for me in 2010. What do you see?

Comment: Is the errorbar width 12pt for you? It was only showing at 4 or so for me.

Comment: Yes, it was. Same in 2016.

Comment: well this is frustrating. I must have something formatted wrong in the chart

Comment: Can you post a workbook somewhere?

Comment: The only way I can replicate is with `On Error Resume Next` and `YourChartObject.ProtectFormatting = True` which only resembles your trouble when the chart and error bars have already been created, and protection is set after.  Maybe a little more info will help.  Do they change at all after creation?  Can you change the weight manually after your sub runs?  If you step through it and watch the eB object in the locals window, does it change there?

Comment: I wound up deleting my code and re-writing without any With statements (or restricting them). Seemed to work, but I don't think the problem was with both Series and ErrorBars objects having a Weight property.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with `.HasErrorBars = True` which already creates an error bar automatically if one is not present, while the next line `.ErrorBar` creates another.

At this point you have two error bars, and `.Format.Line.Weight = 12` in my case affected only the first automatically added one.

Try setting `.HasErrorBars = False` before using `.ErrorBar` and see if it makes a difference.

```
.HasErrorBars = False
.ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlErrorBarIncludeBoth, Type:=xlErrorBarTypeCustom, Amount:="=GraphicSchedule!$" & getColumn(objList.ListColumns.Item("BarLength").Range.Column) & "$" & sourceRow, MinusValues:="=GraphicSchedule!$" & getColumn(objList.ListColumns.Item("BarLength").Range.Column) & "$" & sourceRow
```

*Another thing to try is to toggle the `.Format.Line.Visible` after changes to refresh.

Answer (score -2):

As per Microsoft documentation, you need to use 'weight' :

ErrorBars --> Border : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174210%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Border --> Weight : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa215968%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: could you tell me why -2? it was mentionned official documentation which I did to explain why using weight...??